# SQL average between rows in 2 tables

Tags: mysql

I am running this SQL query:

```
select sec_to_time(avg(time_to_sec(timediff(u.datetime, t.datetime)))) as time FROM tickets t 
                        JOIN ticket_updates u ON 
                        t.ticketnumber = u.ticketnumber 
                            WHERE 
                                DATE(t.datetime) = '2016-05-05' AND 
                                t.customer='Y' AND 
                                u.type='update'
                        ;
```

### Database Schema

```
tickets
   ticketnumber -> INT
   datetime -> DATETIME
ticket_updates
   ticketnumber -> INT
   datetime -> DATETIME
```

### Some Example Data

```
tickets
   ticketnumber   datetime 
   1234           '2016-04-28 09:00:00'
   1235           '2016-04-28 11:00:00'

ticket_updates
   ticketnumber   datetime 
   1234           '2016-04-28 12:00:00'
   1234           '2016-04-28 15:00:00'
   1235           '2016-04-28 13:00:00'
   1235           '2016-04-28 16:00:00'
```

***I am looking for the average response time for all the tickets. This would be based on the first update for each ticket - all others are irrelevant.***

For this data, that would be 2:30 hours:

1. For ticket 1234, the response time is 3 hrs (created 9:00, first updated 12:00)
2. For ticket 1235, the response time is 2 hrs (created 11:00, first updated 13:00)

The average then would be (3+2)/2 = 2.5

The current output is based on all rows in `ticket_updates` but I only want it to look at the earliest added row in `ticket_updates`

Please guide me on how to make it work like that.

Comment: Can you give more context on what you are trying to do? DB structure, example data, and expected output?

Comment: so i am selecting the average from all rows with todays date and based on each row in `tickets` and then the rows in `ticket_updates` but i want to change it to not select all rows in `ticket_updates` and just select the row that was added first (with the earliest date)

Comment: Ok, I think I have a better understanding. Can you provide some example data as well though? That way I can ensure the correct answer for your situation. @charlie

Comment: Expected output as well please @charlie

Comment: check my update for sample data

Comment: Expected output for the sample data please @charlie

Comment: current output is `10:00:00` (10 hours) but these dates it should be returning `02:30:00` (2.5 hours) - the correct output should be based on the earliest dates for each `ticketnumber` in `ticket_updates` (ticket 1234 - `2016-04-28 12:00:00` and ticket 1235 - `2016-04-28 13:00:00`)

Comment: How are you getting 2.5 hours? @charlie

Comment: Ticket 1234 opened at 09.00 first update 12.00 = 3 hours Ticket 1235 opened at 11.00 first update 13.00 = 2 hours  Total hours = 5 hours divided by 2 (two tickets) = 2.5 hours

Comment: I see. So you are looking for the average time for all tickets between their opening and first update times, which is just 1 number. @charlie Am I right?

Comment: That's correct :) so it's an average response time on all tickets for a certain date

Comment: Alright, this makes much more sense now. I will make a query as soon as I get home. I'm on mobile now. @charlie

Comment: Ah okay thank you very much :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright, try this and let me know how it goes.

```
SELECT SEC_TO_TIME(AVG(time_diff)) as avg_response_time 
FROM(
   SELECT TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND,t.datetime, MIN(u.datetime)) as time_diff
   FROM tickets as t
   JOIN ticket_updates as u on u.ticketnumber= t.ticketnumber
   WHERE 
     DATE(t.datetime) = '2016-05-05' AND 
     t.customer='Y' AND 
     u.type='update'
   GROUP BY t.ticketnumber
) AS a;
```